# Can not access environment variable in Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created a Nodejs Lambda function to use **Environment variables** based on: [AWS Lambda Environment Variables - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html)

And I tried to access the environment with `process.env` but it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log('The A varialbe is: ', process.env.A)
    console.log('\n')
    console.log('The all varialbes in process.env is: ', process.env)
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

You can see I already set a variable here:

[image]

But `process.env.A` return undefined and in `process.env` it does not contain my variable `A`

You can see actual result here:

[image]

Comment: Have you clicked the "save" button on the console after set the env var ?

Comment: @ChouW, I did it, I tried a lot of time but no success

Comment: Well... I think I found the root cause :  your env var must satisfy regular expression `[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9_])+`

Comment: Try using `AA` instead `A`, it works for me.

Comment: Thank you a lot @ChouW, I got it worked, `[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9_])+` where you find it, I can not find it in docs.

Comment: I posted the screenshot below, glad to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I create the Lambda you described above, and got the error from the console.

> your env var must satisfy regular expression `[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9_])+`

[image]

Comment: the next time, I think I should disable some block ads extensions, I can not see the error, thank you a lot!